# Ansible Dynamic Inventory fails to get vagrant hosts

Tags: python, vagrant, ansible, ansible-inventory

Trying to invoke Ansible using dynamic inventory. 
Created a .py script to get vagrant box information and the output is .json. 
Below is the picture showing that

1. dynamic_inventory.py is executable
2. `python dynamic_inventory.py --list` returns the .json
3. invoking this thru ansible returns error

Ansible version 1.9.2

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess there is no shebang line at the beginning of the script. Add one line this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Ansible dynamic inventory script can be off any kind of executable script, not just Python. So Ansible doesn't run this with `python dynamic_scripts.py`, rather it uses shebang line to determine the script type. That's why you are getting the error even though the script is executable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.